# Second Monitor Intel graphics card

Tags: screen, intel, monitor

I have a second monitor which works perfectly fine on Windows. However, on Ubuntu 13.10 I am running into a couple of weird issues:

If I connect it after booting Ubuntu, it duplicates the display of my laptop screen (at my laptop screen's resolution). The screen is however not detected in "Displays" and I cannot do anything with it.

If I connect it before booting, it goes straight to CLI and I cannot startx. It says "No screens found".

```
X -configure
```

also fails, saying that the number of created screens does not match the number of detected devices.

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

For anyone that might encounter that in the future, it was a problem with Ubuntu 12.04 not having a proper Intel driver. Could not install a new one either, because it required a new version of libglib, which would break compatibility with a lot of packages.

What I did was an upgrade with `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` to 12.10 (Quantal) - 2x screen worked, but stuff was slow- and then to 13.10 (Saucy). I had it installed with Wubi, so upgrading to 14.04 would break my system.